# Установка приложения на сервер

Tags: centos, centos7

есть инструкция об установке приложения , в инструкции есть команды 
apt-add-repository ppa:  ..... 
apt install ....

но когда я ввожу у меня ошибка command not fount как я понимаю команды для Ubunta
и скорей всего  у меня не такая операционная система на сервере 
подскажите как запустить эти команды

если я не ошибаюсь сервер у меня  CentOS 7.4.1708 Linux server.domain.com 4.16.1-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64

Comment: А какое именно приложение устанавливается?
Mожно попробовать заменить `apt`  на `yum`

Comment: В CentOS используется менеджер пакетов [Yum](https://habr.com/post/301292/)

Comment: единственный возможный ответ: ищите другую инструкцию, написанную для вашего дистрибутива.